# Aggregation for a DynamoDB table

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams, nosql-aggregation

I have a DynamoDB table with 10000 entries and I want to perform the sum of a specific attribute for all of these entries.
At the same time, there are lots of updates coming in every second - 10000 updates every second.

The problem is the fact that reading 10000 DDB entries from a single host is very slow.

Q: What is the best way to do this aggregation keeping in mind the fact I need the output sum written to another DDB table every second ?

My current two options I'm thinking about are:

1. Cache in front of DDB table (such as DAX - Dynamo DB Accelerator)
2. DDB Streams for all of the changes => which get fed into a Kinesis stream => have a host that processes the changes => Writes them to the output table 1/sec

Q: Also how should the single point of failure be addressed regarding both options, as we only have 1 host performing the aggregation.

Looking forward to hear some other suggestions and better ways of doing this.

Comment: I think you need to explain more about your needs. You have a table with just 10,000 items but you're updating 10,000 times a second? Are you overwriting them in place? Where's these updates come from? Why must you aggregate every second? Why are you using one host? How slow is slow? How fast does it have to be? Etc.

Comment: Sure, some more explanations to clarify: 

- I have a table in which 10000 hosts write an item each: Key = Host1, Value = V1
- Each host updates the table 1/sec, by overwriting them 
- I need to aggregate to have a total of these values, which then will enable some decisions to be taken. Think of the hosts writing their backlog count, and the sum the total backlog of work units to be processed. 
- I am using a single host to do the aggregation, however it can be done with multiple hosts as a map reduce. 
- From a single host to read, it takes like 10 seconds even with parallel scans

Comment: The target is to achieve the aggregation in 1 seecond, so I can write it back to a DDB table

Comment: You should use a different technology than DynamoDB. Even if you hit the performance target, the cost will be over $5,000/mo to maintain 10,000 RCU and 10,000 WCU with all those reads/writes every second.

Comment: 1. What solution would you recommend for DynamoDB, disregarding the cost ? 

2. What other technology do you recommend ? How would the solution look like ?

Comment: Looking forward to hear some other suggestions and better ways of doing this.

Comment: Your requirements aren't specific enough to give an opinion. You seem to want HA. Why? Yet you want a single aggregation host. Why? You want to persist the data separately then aggregate, but overwrite the data repeatedly. Why not just keep a running total against the streaming data? Anyway, StackOverflow isn't usually for "hey help me pick a technology" questions.